# Xampp Phpmyadmin stopped working

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, xampp

When i open mysql it's give Following Error.

[image]

MYSQL Error code '2002'

Comment: Does this happen on a fresh install of XAMPP? Otherwise please post (redacted) config files for your XAMPP

Comment: check this http://forum.wampserver.com/read.php?2,87426,page=4

Comment: Start mysql using Xampp.

Comment: Are you using localhost?

Comment: You can just copy and paste error messages here using the clipboard. There's no need to go though the hassle of taking a screen-shot and uploading it and it's actually easier to read and indexable.

Answer (score 0):

Stop the xampp services and restart again!
sometimes even having mysql on pc doesnot allow the xampp services to start so make sure you have removed all sql servers!

Answer (score 0):

If the restart doesn't help then locate the my.ini file somewhere in your installation directory and change the socket file location ..

Thanks